# Issue with PHP trim() - removing "https://" from the string, a strange issue

Tags: php, trim

I'm using PHP trim() to remove https:// from a sting.

```
trim('https://www.hakanerenler.net', 'https://')
```

If i write .com to the domain, its working fine. But if its a .net domain, the last T dissapear.
Why sould if the trimming the last "T" of .net

```
echo  trim('https://www.hakanerenler.com', 'https://');
    returns "www.hakanerenler.com"

echo  trim('https://www.hakanerenler.net', 'https://');
returns "www.hakanerenler.ne"
```

Thanks

Comment: The second argument to trim is a set not a sequential string.  Try using preg_replace instead.

Comment: You can use `ltrim()` instead. However, if is `https://h...` it will remove the "h". Better using a regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`trim` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) removes *any of the supplied characters*, not literal matches. Since `.net` contains a `t` is removing it.

You should use [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace) instead. For more advanced manipulations you could consider [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url)